# Display entity reference in Angular binding

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am writing a pipe that displays infinity (∞) symbol when the input value is larger than a trigger point:

```
transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    if (typeof value == "number") {
        if (value == 10000000) {
            return "&infin;";
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The problem is that the infinity symbol is displayed `&infin;` instead of the actual symbol. What is the correct way to display entity reference (or character) in an angular binding?

Comment: look at your question the infinity symbol seems right. isn't it?

Comment: the important part of the question is "in Angular binding". {{charHere}} wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ascii char directy such as:

```
export class InfPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    if (typeof value == "number") {
      if (value == 10000000) {
        return "∞";
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

if you want directly copy from code then there is stackbitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/infexamplefahim?file=src/app/Infpipe.ts